# running Arduino board on timer if RTC failed

Tags: c++, c, arduino, arduino-ide

I am trying to run my program either arduino timer or RTC . pseudo code look like this

If rtc is failed
yes: read arduino time
else: read rtc time

We can detect if error in RTC SO my question is how can run arduino board on arduino time.From Where it stopped.

main.c

```
    #include "glob.h"
#include "rtc.h"
#include "config.h"

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
   rtcSetup();
}
void loop()
{
  getRTCDateTime();
  convertUTCtoLocal();
  Print_Date();
  Print_Time(); 
RTC_Error_Check();
  Serial.println("................................");
  delay(1000);
}

void Print_Date(){
  Serial.print("Local Date:");
  Serial.print(local_day);
  Serial.print("/");
  Serial.print(local_month);
  Serial.print("/");
  Serial.println(local_year);
}
void Print_Time()
{ Serial.print("local_time is:");
  Serial.print(local_h);
  Serial.print("-");
  Serial.print(local_m);
  Serial.print("-");
  Serial.println(local_s);


}
```

config.h

```
#ifndef CONFIG_H
#define CONFIG_H

#define DEFAULT_TIMEZONE 5.5;



//
#define USER_DATA //User set time in UTC
#define USER_DAY 3;
#define USER_MONTH 1;
#define USER_YEAR 2013;
#define USER_H 7;// MAKE IT AS 14 
#define USER_M 32;// MAKE IT AS 30  FOR SETTING TIME TO 9.0
#define USER_S 0;
#endif
```

rtc.h

```
#ifndef RTC_H
#define RTC_H



void rtcSetup();
void getRTCDateTime();

#endif
```

rtc_c

```
#include "glob.h"
#include "rtc.h"

#include "Wire.h"

void rtcSetup(){
    Wire.begin();
}

#define DS1307_ADDRESS 0x68
byte zero = 0x00; //workaround for issue #527

void getRTCDateTime()
{

  // Reset the register pointer
  Wire.beginTransmission(DS1307_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write(zero);
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.requestFrom(DS1307_ADDRESS, 7);


  s = bcdToDec(Wire.read());
  m = bcdToDec(Wire.read());
  h = bcdToDec(Wire.read() & 0b111111); //24 hour time
  wkDay = bcdToDec(Wire.read()); //0-6 -> sunday - Saturday
  dd = bcdToDec(Wire.read());
  mm = bcdToDec(Wire.read());



}



void rtc_write(){

Wire.beginTransmission(DS1307_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write(zero); //stop Oscillator

  Wire.write(decToBcd(s));
  Wire.write(decToBcd(m));
  Wire.write(decToBcd(h));
  Wire.write(decToBcd(wkDay));
  Wire.write(decToBcd(dd));
  Wire.write(decToBcd(mm));
  Wire.write(decToBcd(getLastTwoDigOfYear(yy)));

  Wire.write(zero); //start

  Wire.endTransmission();


}

byte decToBcd(byte val){
  // Convert normal decimal numbers to binary coded decimal
  return ( (val/10*16) + (val%10) );
}

byte bcdToDec(byte val)  {
  // Convert binary coded decimal to normal decimal numbers
  return ( (val/16*10) + (val%16) );
}

int getLastTwoDigOfYear(int y){
 return(y%1000); 
}






void getuserdate()
{
  byte s = 45; //0-59
  byte m =47; //0-59
  byte h =15; //0-23
  byte wkDay =2; //1-7
  byte dd =20;


  byte mm =       3; //1-12
  byte yy  =       13; //0-99

}
```

calc.h

```
#ifndef CALC_H
#define CALC_H



void calcTime();
void convertSecondsToLocalHMS(int secs);
void convertUTCtoLocal();

static int MNTH_DAYS[12]={
  31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

#endif
```

calc_time.c

```
#include"timecalc.h"

#include"config.h"
#include "glob.h"
#include "rtc.h"
#include "Time.h"
#include<math.h>

static long tzone_offset_s = tzone*3600UL;


void calcTime(){
  #ifndef USER_DATA

     getRTCDateTime();

    #else         
  getDefaultDateTime();
  #endif


convertUTCtoLocal();
hdec = local_h + float(local_m)/60;//hours in decimal

}



void getDefaultDateTime(){

  Serial.println("DEFAULT DATE AND TIME IS USING");
  latitude = DEFAULT_LATITUDE;
  longitude = DEFAULT_LONGITUDE;
  mm = USER_MONTH;
  yy = USER_YEAR;
  dd = USER_DAY;
  h = USER_H;
  m = USER_M;
  s = USER_S; 
}

void convertUTCtoLocal(){

  long no_s_day_start= h*3600UL + m*60 + s; //no of seconds since day start
  long day_change_cutoff_s = 86400UL-tzone_offset_s;//max utc before changing date

  long additional_s;//additional seconds after day change

  local_year = yy;

  if(no_s_day_start>day_change_cutoff_s){
    if(dd+1 > MNTH_DAYS[mm-1]){
      local_day = 1;
      if(mm==12){
        local_month=1;
        local_year = yy+1;
      }
      else
        local_month = mm+1;
    }
    else{
      local_day=dd+1;
      local_month=mm;
    }

    additional_s = no_s_day_start - day_change_cutoff_s; 
    convertSecondsToLocalHMS(additional_s);

  }
  else{
    local_day = dd;
    local_month = mm;
    convertSecondsToLocalHMS(no_s_day_start+tzone_offset_s);
  }



}


void convertSecondsToLocalHMS(long secs){

  local_h = secs/3600; //hour
  local_m=(secs%3600)/60;//min
  local_s = secs - local_h*3600UL - local_m*60;
}


int sign(int v)
{
  return v >= 0 ? 1 : -1;
}
```

diag.h

```
#ifndef DIAG_H
#define DIAG_H

static int Error_count;
static int RTC_ERROR;
void RTC_Error_Check();
static int ph;
static int pm;
static int ps;
static int start_time;
static int p_time;
static int rtcwrite_count;

#endif
```

diag.c

```
#include"glob.h"
#include"rtc.h"
#include"diag.h"
void RTC_Error_Check()
{
  int count=0;
  Serial.println("take reading fun called");
   ph=h;
   pm=m;
   ps=s;
   RTC_ERROR=Check_RTC();
   if(RTC_ERROR=0)
   {
     Error_count=0;
   }else
   {
     Error_count=Error_count+1;
   }

   if(Error_count==6)
   {
      Get_Ard_time();ps=ps+1;
   }



}

void Get_Ard_time()
{
   ph=h;
   pm=m;
   ps=s;
   start_time=(3600*h)+(60*m)+s;

    Serial.println("start time is:");
  Serial.println(start_time);
  Serial.println("previous time is:");
  Serial.println(p_time);
   if(start_time==p_time)
   {
     h=ph;

        m=pm;

        s=ps;
     if(s>59)
          {s=0;
          m=m+1;
          }          
          if(m>59)
           { m=0;
             h=h+1;
           }
            if(h>23)
              {
               h=0;}
        rtcWrite();
     p_time=start_time;
   }else 
   {
       getRTCDateTime();

   }

}
```

Comment: Do Aruino RTC's fail so often that you need an explicit check for it?

Answer (score 1):

you might find some hints here:
http://playground.arduino.cc//Code/Time